# Is it possible to connect my android app to mysql database with out PHP.?

Tags: android, mysql

Is it possible to connect my android app to mysql database with out PHP.?
if it is possible what is the alternative way for connecting to mysql db.

Comment: Down voter could u provide comments plz..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Yes, You can.
```

You have to add a jar library for mysql.Then java code that will connect to the mysql server.

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;

import android.database.SQLException;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;


    public class SQLConnection {
        public static Connection conn = null;
        static void setConnection(String user,String pass,String urlServer,String dBase){   


              try
              {
                  String userName = user;
                  String password = pass;
                  String url = "jdbc:mysql://"+urlServer+"/"+dBase;

                  Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();
                  conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url, userName, password);
                  System.out.println ("Database connection established");
              }
              catch (Exception e)
              {
                  System.err.println (e.getMessage());
              }
              finally
              {
              }


        }
        public static Connection getConnection(){
        return conn;
        }

    }
```

Comment: thank you . your answer is very useful..
for accepting u r answer i dont have points.

Comment: @dianuj could you give me any sample tutorial for this.

Comment: @Priyanka, you still facing a problem.

Comment: yes.i need a basic tutorial for this.

Comment: Once you connect with db, you would be able to pass all the query from java that is supported by mysql.And in java, operation is same for all database server.You only have to connect them first.Were you able to connect the database?