# How to connect MySQL database from android?

Tags: android, mysql

I am creating an android application from one week but I am not able to succeed.

I searched in google and in many other forum but I am not getting the server connection.

If any one knows how to connect server then please explain me with simple code.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619909/is-it-possible-to-connect-my-android-app-to-mysql-database-with-out-php/12620144#12620144

Comment: Down voter could u provide comments plz

Answer (score 1):

Using Web Services

- SOAP > [How to call a SOAP web service on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-soap-web-service-in-android)
- JSON > http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: I tried using json but its showing Null pointer exception

Comment: then why you ask this question dear ? ask new question with code

Comment: Yes u r rite. But I want to know whole process thats why I asked.

Answer (score 1):

You don't connect directly to the ddbb, instead, you should create a webservice with your preferred server language (c#, php, etc) which will handle the ddbb connection and business logic, passing the data to the android application using SOAP or JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I once had the same problem and found the following link, it helped me much, **BUT** later i realized, that you should not do it at all, and should use an easy to create web service.

how ever if you want to make your own experience take this link:
[MySql via Android](http://shariqmobin.wordpress.com/2010/03/06/hello-world/)